# defining a measure of unique value counts

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, powerpivot

How do I define a measure in a data model (withing the PowerPivot feature) with a formula that needs to get a unique count of values.  For example, something like this:

```
reset_rate := UNIQUECOUNT([col_a])/UNIQUECOUNT([col_b])
```

obviously, there is no such function as `UNIQUECOUNT()`, the closest is `COUNTA()`, which won't give me what I need.  Is there a way to get an equivalent calculation with existing functions?

**NOTE: this is within the Data Model editor, not in the spreadsheet.**

Answer (score 1):

The Data Model formula is DISTINCTCOUNT, e.g.

`reset_rate := DISTINCTCOUNT([col_a])/DISTINCTCOUNT([col_b])`

Here's the MSDN doco, which is not very useful:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492142.aspx

Here's a better reference, covering several variations:

http://www.daxpatterns.com/distinct-count/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this formula `=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(data,data))`

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586815/count-unique-values-in-a-column-in-excel) for your reference.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT` isn't available for measures as far as I could tell

Comment: Have you tried it if not please try.. If you think it won't work there are more ways to achieve. Please click on the link and go through the page, it will surely help you :)

Comment: I have.  Have you before giving this advice?

Comment: Yes its working :)

Comment: Oh just now i saw the NOTE added by you, if its not in the spec sheet you might not get the proper result..